Excel take nth to last value with multiple criteria
I need help with an Excel formula to extract the nth to last value in a data set with multiple criteria.
I have come across this formula which extracts the last (or nth to last) value where the specified name (A1) matches the range.
=Index(F:F,small(if(B:B=A1,row(B:G)-min(row(B:G))+1),countif(B:B,A1)))
I am taking the last three values so I have simply repeated this formula 3 times changing the nth to last number each time. This formula is working correctly to bring across the correct values.
However I have some additional data in column I which I only want to include the figure in column F if column I is blank. I have tried to include this as a second IF formula after the first one but it seems to be breaking the entire formula. For example =index(F:F,small(if(B:B=A1,if(I:I="",row(B:G)-min(row(B:G)))+1),countif(B:B,A1)))
In summary I am looking to return the last, 2nd last and 3rd last values in column F, where the value in column B matches A1 and the value in column I is blank.
Can anyone help me with the final piece of the formula? Thanks in advance.
Ash

If you have Excel 365: look into TAKE - using a negative value the last n items are returned: https://exceljet.net/functions/take-function

This formula gives the below result integrated with testing I column.
=INDEX(F:F,SMALL(IF((B:B=A1)*(I:I=""),ROW(B:G)-MIN(ROW(B:G))+1),COUNTIFS(B:B,A1,I:I,"")-{0,1,2}))
It is recommended to define only the rows in the ranges which are really used because of reducing execution time.


If you have Microsoft 365 (to use FILTER), could you try
=SMALL(
FILTER($F$2:$F$20,(B2:$B$20=$A$1) * ($I$2:$I$20=""))
,SEQUENCE(3))

